# How to call method without method name in python

Tags: python, pytorch

```
class LinearRegression(nn.Module):
def __init__(self,input_size,output_size):
    # super function. It inherits from nn.Module and we can access everythink in nn.Module
    super(LinearRegression,self).__init__()
    # Linear function.
    self.linear = nn.Linear(input_dim,output_dim)

def forward(self,x):
    return self.linear(x)


input_dim = 1
output_dim = 1
model = LinearRegression(input_dim,output_dim)
```

> In this code block when I want to call forward method in model object I can call 2 different ways

The first way

```
results = model.forward(car_price_tensor)
```

Second way

```
results = model(car_price_tensor)
```

And I try the second way on a different class and object it doesnt work. How it possible?

Comment: If that works, it's because `nn.Module` class implements `__call__` method to call forward method, yoru other class seems to not implement `__call__` method

Comment: These are two completely different functions. Try stepping through the code in debug and see what happens.

Comment: How the call method work?

Comment: `foo.__call__()` implements what happens when you run `foo()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This behavior that lets you call a Python object like a function is enabled through a special method `__call__`, some explanation [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/__call__-in-python/).

A `torch.nn.Module` is a class that implements this behavior. You class `LinearRegression` is a subclass of it so it inherits this behavior. By default the `__call__` method is derived from your `forward` implementation **but it not the same**.

The difference in behavior is explained [here](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/any-different-between-model-input-and-model-forward-input/3690).